# Prove $X\sim N(0,1)$, $Y = 2X \Rightarrow (X,Y)$ lacks a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability, integration, analysis

I want to show $X\sim N(0,1)$, $Y = 2X \Rightarrow (X,Y)$ lacks a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The intuition for why this should be so is explained very well in [this answer to a similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263506/understanding-degenerate-multivariate-normal-distribution/263525#263525); $(X,Y)$ follows a degenerate bivariate normal distribution and the graph of its (false) density is volumeless. However, this intuition doesn't amount to a proof (one would need to show something like: if a density exists, it must be a limit of bivariate normal densities as $\rho \rightarrow 1$; but this limit fails to be a density). At my level, the only viable approach to this problem seems to be to write the distribution function of $(X,Y)$ as
$$
F(x,y)=P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=F_{\Phi}\left(min\left(x,\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{min\left(x,\frac{y}{2}\right)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\mathrm{d}t
$$
and try to show that there is no $f(s,t)$ such that for each $x$ and each $y$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{min\left(x,\frac{y}{2}\right)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x f(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{.}
$$
However, I am not sure how to show this (if it is even possible directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: If $(X,Y)$ possesses a density $f(x,y)$ then we must have
$$P((X,Y)\in B)=\int_B f(x,y)\,dx dy\tag1$$
for any set $B$. Now take $B:=\{(x,y): y=2x\}$. By construction, we know that $$P((X,Y)\in B)=P(Y=2X)=1;$$ however, the expression $(1)$ will give a value of zero for any possible $f(x,y)$, since $(1)$ will be the integral of $f(x,y)$ over a region of measure zero.

Comment: If you need to justify it further, this implies that the measure induced on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the random variable $Z = (X,Y)$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, so there is no Radon-Nikodym derivative, i.e., distribution function.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this! Thank you

Comment: @JohannaOosterhof If you felt the answer is helpful (since you’ve accepted it) you may also want to consider giving it an upvote by pressing the UP arrow

Comment: @SBF I will as soon as I have enough reputation to do so!